# Word gets stuck during export via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel VBA script contains an export function which results in one Word document of about 12 pages.

On my private computer, this works.

On my company's laptop this seems to take too long and probably some kind of Word watchdog is triggered. Word gets stuck after about 75% of the code and the message "Word has stopped working" pops up.

I determined the point where it gets too much for Word to handle. As the export code is quite extensive and also contains several company and project details that I don't want to reveal, I prefer to not post it here.

Here is the snippet at which Word gets stuck:

```vb
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Backup - Do not change").Shapes("companyLogo").Copy
With wdFrontHeaderTable
    .rows.Height=30
    With .Cell(1,1).Range
        .Paste
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment=0
    End With
    With .Cell(1,1).Range.InlineShapes(.Cell(1,1).Range.InlineShapes.Count)
        .LockAspectRatio=msoTrue
        .Width=120 'this one still works
    End With 'here, the error occurs
End With
```

If I set one before that point and then run the two halves of code, one after another, it works.
If I uncomment the whole block, the error occurs in the next block.

The code does what it is supposed to do, even on the company laptop. I guess it just takes too long and the watchdog "thinks" Word was stuck.

Is there a way to disable the watchdog or another way to solve this?

I tried Application.Wait (1000).

Word is initialized by

```vb
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
```

Comment: do you have any Word events handling code active?

Comment: None that I am aware of, no.

Comment: well, just look at the word document VBA Project code to be sure of that

Comment: Ah, I was misunderstanding. The word doc does not have any VBA code itself, all VBA is in the Excel file.

Comment: I see
Maybe your'e opening too many Word instances (one per wanted doc) and not disposing them?

Comment: The macro only exports one single document and only one instance of Word is used for that. Good remark, I'll clarify that in the problem description.